# What's difference between node_revision__field_X and node__field_X tables in Drupal 8?

Tags: entities, 8

I'm in the process of migrating a complex D6 site up to D8 using the Migration tool. An old table `content_field_gallery` seems to have been migrated to a `node_revision__field_gallery` table, but there is also a `node__field_gallery` table with about half as many rows.

I'm guessing that the `node__field_X` version has only the latest revision and the `node_revision__field_X` has ALL revisions. Is that correct? Isn't that redundant? And a good index should make a single table pretty efficient? Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. This is the same data structure as in Drupal 7.

It would be possible to write a different backend that only uses one table, there was a project for that for Drupal 7 but I think it never really took off.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2083451 for a discussion if that's still necessary or not.

Comment: Thanks! I skipped D7 so having a hard time understanding all the differences.